# How to eliminate the nested loop in my R code

Tags: r, loops

I have a csv file which contains 3 columns (user_id, item_id, score). I want to create a matrix with user_id as rows, item_id as columns, the score as corresponding entry. The purpose of doing this is to enable machine learning analysis on the matrix.
There are 180K rows and it takes about 2.5 mins for the code below. How to make it faster? There are about 1K unique user_ids and 9K unique item ids.  user_id and item_id are long integers, score is from 1 to 5.

```
location <- "data.csv"
data <- read.csv(location, header = TRUE)

user_id <- data[,1]
item_id <- data[,2]
score <- data[,3]


unique_user_id <- unique(unlist(user_id))
unique_item_id <- unique(unlist(item_id))

user_item <- matrix(0,nrow=length(unique_user_id), ncol=length(unique_item_id))

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  row <- match(data[i,1],unique_user_id)
  col <- match(data[i,2],unique_item_id)
  user_item[row,col] <- data[i,3]
}
```

sample input:

```
user_id      item_id    score
 10000001     101          1
 10000001     102          2
 10000002     103          2
 10000001     104          3
```

sample  output

```
       1      2    3    4      
  1    1      2         3
  2                2
  3
```

Of course, I need to have two tables hash the output row and column index to original user id and item id.  Any better representation is appreciated, but I do need the matrix form of storing (user,item,score) as above

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? give us an example of the input and expected output

Comment: Perhaps, see something like `xtabs(score ~ user_id + item_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use reshape function from stats package.

```
tab<-data.frame(ID=rep(1:25,4),Fact=rep(c('A','B','C','D'),each=25),
                                  Resp=sample(1:5,size=100,replace=T))

> head(tab)
  ID Fact Resp
1  1    A    1
2  2    A    5
3  3    A    2
4  4    A    1
5  5    A    2
6  6    A    4

res<-reshape(tab,idvar='ID',timevar='Fact',direction='wide')

head(res)
> head(res)
  ID Resp.A Resp.B Resp.C Resp.D
1  1      1      3      1      4
2  2      5      4      4      3
3  3      2      2      4      2
4  4      1      4      5      5
5  5      2      2      4      4
6  6      4      2      5      2
```